# Merge two css class for div element

Tags: css, html

I have below css classes and want to merge to one,

```
.classA {
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
}

.classB {
 height: 800px;
}

.classB > div {
 xxxx
 yyyy
}

.classA > div {
 xxxx
 yyyy
}
```

Here 'ClassA > div' and 'classB > div' have the same properties. So i need to make this as single class to apply to div element.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a comma:

```
.classA > div, .classB > div {
 xxxx
 yyyy
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `,`.

```
ClassA > div , classB > div { /* css rules */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this:

```
.classA > div, .classB > div {
    xxxx
    yyyy   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.classB > div, 
.classA > div 
{
   xxxx
   yyyy
}
```

Just use a comma