# multiple css structure options

Tags: html, css

I've got a CSS structure problem regarding multiple items with the same contents.

What I want is for there to be two divs, one with a class of `right` and another with a class of `left`. They both have several links inside of them with no classes attached to them. What I want is to be able to simply do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.left or div.right > a {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="right">
  <a href="google.com">test</a>
</div>

<div class="left">
  <a href="google.com">test2</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I know that won't work, but I was wondering if there was an alternative method of doing this.

Comment: Do you want to accomplish to style both hyperlinks in one css-statement?

Comment: div.left or div.right > a { to div.left > a,div.right > a {

Comment: sorry, didnt see already answer posted.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285518/how-to-target-a-group-of-long-similar-css-selectors-on-one-line/25286385#25286385

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676961/merge-two-css-class-for-div-element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use like below.

```
div.left > a, div.right > a {
background-color: yellow;
}
```